# setTimeout and Popup Ad code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying for apply a delay for my popup ad code, it's programmated for start onclick. This is the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='URL'></script>
```

I have apply setTimeout in this way:

```
<script type='text/javascript'  setTimeout(function() { src='URL' }, 2000);></script>
```

The popup start but without delay.

Comment: that's not how you Javascript.

Comment: I can't apply a delay?

Comment: What do you think `src='URL'` is doing?

Comment: "src" open a external script.

Comment: src is just a variable. It is not going to do anything other than set the variable. BUT it is not going to run because it is not a valid script.

Comment: Please take a look at some basic JavaScript examples, your code needs to be between the script tags. <script>code</script>

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to delay a script's execution in that manner. The `setTimeout` function is not available outside of scripts - in your case, you're trying to use it in the middle of your HTML.

You can delay a script's execution by using another script though. In this example below, I generate a script tag dynamically and append it to the head after two seconds:

```html
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'http://example.com/some/script.js';
    document.head.appendChild(s);
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: And hopefully the script does not use document.write. :)

Comment: Haha, yes. If the target script expects to be run synchronously and uses `document.write` you're out of luck. Unless, you want to do some messy hacks involving overwriting of the native `document.write` function.

Comment: I'm testing this code. Thanks.

Comment: I have tested. Popup start but I not see delay. How I can overwriting document.write?

Comment: @GDaquila You should open a new question with information and code samples of the script you're trying to deploy. It's not possible to help without more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  setTimeout(function() { 
    var my_script = document.createElement('script');
    my_script.setAttribute('src',URL);
    document.head.appendChild(my_script);
  }, 2000);
</script>
```